# VBA ignore System Separators Setting on opening CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, separator, list-separator

In my Windows OS, I set my "Date, time or number formats" with the following separators:
Decimal: ","
Milesimal: "."
List: ";"

[image]

In excel, I set in File > Options > Advanced > Use System Separators (ticked)

[image]

And when I open my CSV file manually, it goes according to the System Separators (data hidden due to confidential data). In the picture below, each data is in one Column

[image]

---

PROBLEM 1:

But when I asked my VBA macro to Open this CSV file, it totally ignored the System Separators. In the picture below, all data are in the Column A

[image]

The command I used in VBA to open the file was:

`Workbooks.Open (MacroFile.Range("B" & i).Value & "\" & MacroFile.Range("C" & i).Value), UpdateLinks:=False`

Note: It gets the Path + FileName through Cell Content

SOLUTION FOR PROBLEM 1 (credit to @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns):

Added property Local:=True to `Workbooks.Open (MacroFile.Range("B" & i).Value & "\" & MacroFile.Range("C" & i).Value), UpdateLinks:=False, Local:=True`

---

PROBLEM 2:

When I asked my VBA macro to Close+Save this CSV file, it totally ignored the System Separators. It replaced all the ";" with "," list delimiters

The command I used in VBA to Close+Save the file was:

`Workbooks(MacroFile.Range("C" & i).Value).Close SaveChanges:=True`

---

PROBLEM 3:

I've noticed too that when I tried to use the Formula command below, it didn't work, even having Separator as ";"

`File_CSV.Range("Z1").Formula = "=SUMIF(F:F;""C"";G:G)"`

I had to replace for:

`File_CSV.Range("Z1").Formula = "=SUMIF(F:F,""C"",G:G)"`

SOLUTION FOR PROBLEM 3 (Credit for TimWilliams):

Used .FormulaLocal in `File_CSV.Range("Z1").FormulaLocal = "=SUMIF(F:F;""C"";G:G)"`

Comment: When setting  cell formula using `Formula` you should always use the "US" list separator `,`   If you want to use your local list separator then use `FormulaLocal`

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, I didn't know about that and it worked! I'm still facing the VBA ignoring my system separators ):

Comment: The screenshots of your data are not very useful - you can re-take them after using some dummy data if there are concerns over confidentiality.

Comment: Set property `Local` to `True` when opening the workbook and see what happens. [Workbooks.Open method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I inserted the `Local:=True` in the `Workbook.Open` Method and it worked perfectly! It opened with the corrects delimiters. But now I'm having another issue, when I Close+Save with `Workbooks(MacroFile.Range("C" & i).Value).Close SaveChanges:=True`, it replaces the ";" delimiter with "," (U.S.), I tried looking in the https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.save and https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close, but none of them have this "Local" property!

Comment: Try to force it. Do manually the delimiters using VBA. As example, replace all commas with semmicolons and save it. It should keep the semicolons

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, the problem is that VBA replaces from ";" to "," AFTER saving, so I would have to open this CSV with NotePad and "Replace All", do you know if it is possible to open a .CSV with NotePad (non Default program)? I've tried finding it but I couldn't